# Proof of existence of independent set given partition of vertices in a random graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

I'm unsure of how to solve the following question. Intuitively, I am considering using an FKG inequality by creating some increasing and decreasing sequences, but I'm having trouble formalising it.

Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree $d$, and let $V = V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \ldots \cup V_n$ be a partition of the vertices such that $|V_i| \geq 2ed$ for every $i$. Show that there is an independent set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ such that $v_i \in V_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: When you see the number $2e$, you should expect to use the local lemma. But see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788705/prove-or-supply-counter-example-about-graph).